# Close form of a summation of a sequence to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the closed form of the following summation
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-a)^i\frac{\Gamma(M+i)}{\Gamma(N+i)i!}
\end{equation}
where $a$ is a real number, $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the gamma function, and $M$ and $N$ are positive integers and $M<N$.

Seems that this is related to Taylor expansion of the exponential function, but it has some extra terms.

Does this summation has a closed form?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The series 
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(m+j)}{j! \, \Gamma(n+j)} \, (-a)^{j} 
\end{align}
is a confluent hypergeometric series and is given by
\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma(m)}{\Gamma(n)} \, {}_{1}F_{1}(m; n; -a).
\end{align}

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! I will check about it.